# `us:2` mod in XKB configuration

Tags: xkb

This is my XKB configuration:

```
$ setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+gb(custom)+us:2+inet(evdev)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

What is the meaning of `us:2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you have defined two layouts, `gb` with its `custom` variant and `us` with its default one (ie the first one defined in the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` file).

The first layout is not marked with a `:1`, only the second with a `:2`, the third with `:3`, and so on.

Your configuration doesn't define any key to switch between the layouts, so they're probably only switchable via GUI.

For instance, you can define three layouts (US/basic, German and Russian/phonetic), switchable via the <kbd>Menu</kbd> key:

```
$ setxkbmap -layout us,de,ru -variant basic,,phonetic -option grp:menu_toggle
$ setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us(basic)+de:2+ru(phonetic):3+inet(evdev)+group(menu_toggle)+ctrl(nocaps)"  };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)"     };
};
```

If you want to see the complete expanded xkb configuration, you can do it with:

```
xkbcomp $DISPLAY - | less
```

That will show the three layouts as they were merged, eg. for the <kbd>\</kbd> key:

```
xkb_symbols "pc+us(basic)+de:2+ru(phonetic):3+inet(evdev)+group(menu_toggle)+ctrl(nocaps)" {

    name[group1]="English (US)";
    name[group2]="German";
    name[group3]="Russian (phonetic)";
...
    key <BKSL> {
        type[group2]= "FOUR_LEVEL",
        type[group3]= "ALPHABETIC",
        symbols[Group1]= [       backslash,             bar ],
        symbols[Group2]= [      numbersign,      apostrophe, rightsinglequotemark,      dead_breve ],
        symbols[Group3]= [      Cyrillic_e,      Cyrillic_E ]
    };
```

The same `xkbcomp` tool could be used to load a custom configuration without having to be root and mess around with system files and directories inside `/usr/share`:

```
xkbcomp $DISPLAY ~/.xkb_conf
# modify ~/.xkb_conf
# then load it:
xkbcomp ~/.xkb_conf $DISPLAY
```

Adding the last line to `~/.xsession` may or may not work with "modern" desktop environments, which are force-loading the fixed keyboard settings with the C equivalent of `setxkbmap` and are not easily convinced to stay out of the way.